# Show $P\{\xi_1+\dots+\xi_n=1\}=(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i)\Delta + O(\Delta^2)$ (Shiryaev's Probability page 44)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to do the following exercise:

Let $\xi_i,\dots, \xi_n$ be independent Bernoulli random variables such that
$$
P\{\xi_i=0\}=1-\lambda_i \Delta\\
P\{\xi_i=1\}=\lambda_i \Delta
$$
where $\Delta$ is a small number, $\Delta>0,\lambda_i>0$.

Show that
$$
P\{\xi_1+\dots+\xi_n=1\}=(\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i)\Delta + O(\Delta^2)
$$

---

I already wrote out (as already shown in part of @Marcin Malogrosz answer):
$$
P\{\xi_1+\dots+\xi_n) = \sum_i \lambda_i \Delta \prod_{i\neq j} (1-\lambda_j\Delta) \\
\Bigl|\sum_i \lambda_i \Delta \prod_{i\neq j} (1-\lambda_j\Delta) - \sum_i \lambda_i \Delta\Bigr| = \sum_i \lambda_i \Delta \Bigl(1-\prod_{i\neq j} (1-\lambda_j\Delta) \Bigr)
$$
But I am stuck here

---

I am able to show a simplified version with $P\{\xi_i=1\}=\lambda_i\Delta=\lambda\Delta$ (when the $n$ random variables are also identical) as following:
$$
P\{\xi_1+\dots+\xi_n=1\}=\sum_i \lambda\Delta (1-\lambda\Delta)^{n-1}
$$
using Taylor approximation when $\Delta$ is close to $0$ as
$$
\lambda\Delta(1-\lambda\Delta)^{n-1}\Bigr|_{\Delta=0}+\frac{\Delta}{1!}\Bigl\{\lambda(1-\lambda\Delta)^{n-1}-\lambda^2\Delta^2(n-1)(1-\lambda\Delta)^{n-2}\Bigl\}\Bigr|_{\Delta=0} + O(\Delta^2)\\
=\lambda\Delta+O(\Delta^2)
$$
and then sum over $i$.

---

My problem is to show:

$$
\Bigl(1-\prod_{i\neq j} (1-\lambda_j\Delta) \Bigr)=O(\Delta)
$$

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
P(\sum_{i=1}^n\xi_i=1)=\sum_{i=1}^nP(\xi_i=1)\prod_{j\neq i}P(\xi_j=0)=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\Delta\prod_{j\neq i}(1-\lambda_j\Delta)
$$
Now
$$
\Big|P(\sum_{i=1}^n\xi_i=1)-\Delta\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\Big|=\Delta\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i(1-\prod_{j\neq i}(1-\lambda_j\Delta))=\Delta\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_iO(\Delta)=O(\Delta^2)
$$

Comment: I also made progress until this: $\Delta\sum_i \lambda_i(1-\prod_{i\neq j} (1-\lambda_j \Delta))$, but I stuck here. Can you please explain why $(1-\prod_{i\neq j}(1-\lambda_j\Delta)) = O(\Delta)$?

Comment: Let $W(\Delta)=\prod_{j\neq i}(1-\lambda_j\Delta)$. Than $W$ is a polynomial and $W(0)=1$, hence 1-W(\Delta)=\Delta G(\Delta) for a certain polynomial $G$. Since we are interested in the case when $\Delta$ is small |G(\Delta)|=O(1).